# 3d printer firmware compile

Tags: firmware, 3d-printing

i have an ender 3 pro 3d printer, due to hardware upgrades I have needed to change the firmware, unfortunately this hasn't been hassle free, I have got the firmware files from github.com in the marlin section, marlin being the firmware that the 3d printer uses, I have edited the files using VSCode, I have the latest python downloaded which apparently is needed for compiling the firmware, and I downloaded the extension platform IO, but when I try to run the command build it throws me an error code, I have watched tutorials on how to do this and have literally followed them step by step, so I'm not sure whats going on, I don't know if it could potentially be a firewall or something to that effect but honestly I have very little idea,

the error code it throws out is

msbuild : The term 'msbuild' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- msbuild /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /t:build /consoleloggerparam ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (msbuild:String) [], CommandNotF 
  oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

i understand that it is saying that the term MSbuild is undefined but i've done everything on the tutorials have said, is there something obvious i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered giving the “Auto Build Marlin” extension a try?
https://marlinfw.org/docs/basics/auto_build_marlin.html
It should install all needed dependencies and configure the settings.

I don't think I ever had to use msbuild or python to compile Marlin inside VScode. Is it possible that you are trying to build the wrong part of the MarlinFW or the PlatformIO installation had gone wrong (restart?).
Most of the time the only hard part with PlatformIO is configuring the platformio.ini file correctly. Can you share yours?
Additional information about Marlin and PlatformIO under https://marlinfw.org/docs/basics/install_platformio_vscode.html

Answer (score 0):

try checking your system PATH variables. You need to add it to this collection, or you need to open terminal where your executable is and run it from there. Also check for case sensitivity in your command.

The right way of running msbuild is with the dotnet prefix as it is a part of .Net and .Net core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild

Comment: any help doing this? im a bit rusty on coding

Comment: it is saying i need to update my "include path" but once again I'm a bit lost with it.

Comment: Can you provide links to the projects you want to compile? You are saying it should be done with python but the error comes from msbuild.

You can try running `dotnet msbuild` instead of just `msbuild`